# c# wpf: dynamic importing of Listview itemtype styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Situation:
I have a Listbox displaying different objects which are all implementing an interface.

Styling is done by 
`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}">`
All works fine. The Objects of the different classes are redered as intended.

Now I created a library, which adds a new Class, implementing the interface from above.
Additionally it provides its own DataTemplate for being displayed in the Listbox. Which is placed in the libraries App.xaml.

After adding the new class to the listbox it doesn't recognize the provided DataTemplate from the library. It only shows "namespace.classname".

How can I tell the Listbox to recognize the new style for the new Class (or other unknown classes only implementing the interface?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found following steps to solve the issue.

First in the external Plugin.dll project:

- create a new RessourceDictionary in a separate file. I called it StyleDictionary.xaml

```
    <ResourceDictionary ...>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyNewClass}"> ... 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

- Import the Ressource from the dll in the main applications code behind

```
    ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    dictionary.Source = new Uri("/AssemblynameWithoutDLL;component/StyleDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

After that, it is rendered correctly in the listbox.
Now I can dynamically load assemblies(e.g. from a plugin directory) and create some objects which are displayed as intended.
The assemblies' classes need to implement my interface to be identified and there must be "StyleDictionary.xaml" to be read.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell the `Listbox` to recognize the new style for the new Class?

By adding an implicit `DataTemplate` for the new class, just as you did for `MyClass`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}">
            <TextBlock>My Class...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass2}">
            <TextBlock>My Class 2...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
public interface MyInterface { }
public class MyClass : MyInterface { }
public class MyClass2 : MyInterface { }
public class MyClass3 : MyInterface { }
...
lb.ItemsSource = new List<MyInterface> { new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass2(), new MyClass3() };
```

> ...or other unknown classes only implementing the interface?

Using an implicit `DataTemplate` for an interface type like this is *not* supported:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyInterface}">
    <TextBlock>won't be applied to MyClass3 objects...</TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396547/7252182) for more information about why.

This means that you'll have to define another template for `MyClass3`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then i have to change the xaml of the existing file, which i dont want. 
Is there a way to tell the listbox that it should search in all available Ressources for the new template?
The new class/template is loaded dynamically into the application and the listbox just dont know it at compile time.
If not in xaml, maybe there is a way in codebehind to tell the listbox where to look for matching data templates.
Thats what i want to find out.