# WPF TreeWiew with multiple levels and object types

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have the following datas :

```
public class Category {
    string title {get;set;}
    List<Category> Childs {get;set;}
    List<Element> Elements {get;set;}
}

public class Element{
    string Title {get;set;}
    string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to display it in a TreeView and a DataGrid, on x levels deep, like the following example :

```
CategoryA 
    CategoryB
         Element1-Title  Element1-Description (in a gridView)
         Element2-Title  Element2-Description (in a gridView)
CategoryC
    Element3-Title  Element3-Description (in a gridView)
CategoryD 
    CategoryE
         CategoryF
             Element4-Title  Element4-Description (in a gridView)
             Element5-Title  Element5-Description (in a gridView)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks for any advices

Mikke

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add a combined property to hold all of the children of a Category object.

```
public class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => SubCategories.Union(Elements.Cast<object>());
}
```

Build a list of the Category items that form the root level of the tree and assign this (either diectly or via data binding) to the `ItemsSource` of your `TreeView` control.

Then in the `Resouces` section of your TreeView, create a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for Category items which binds to thes combined property for its ItemsSource, and a simple `DataTemplate` for Elements (assuming that Elements never have children).

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootCategories}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Category}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Element}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Hello Peregrine, thanks for your help. It works fine. 

Let's complicate a little more. For my "Element" I have multiple types and all inherits from an IElement. Let's assume I have ElementA, ElementB that inherits from IElement. 

How can I use it in the DataTemplate ? Instead of using local:Element, I Would like to use local:IElement and apply the same visual for every types.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: @IMikkeI You can define a data template for an interface type, but the binding is slightly more complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023441/how-to-bind-datatemplate-datatype-to-interface

Comment: Yes I've tried this. When I use this technique, in each "Element" lane, I have the class name instead of title and description attributes. This worked when I put my DataTemplate in the HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate but the hierarchy of the TreeView is broken then.